# LFTP, download only files created the same day I execute LFTP

Tags: ftp, lftp

How do I make LFTP download a file from a remote server only if this file was created TODAY (the same day I run LFTP) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `mirror`.

It has this `--newer-than=SPEC` option to download only files newer than specified time. For your specific needs, use `--newer-than=now-1days`. Now - 1 day should be yesterday therefore lftp will download all the file newer than yesterday.

Refer here for more info: http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html

EDIT: While I was tweaking my script, I notice there's an `--only-newer` option which download only newer file which is also useful for your case but with slight changes. `--only-newer` check the destination folder and download any files from source that's not in the destination folder while `--newer-than` download any files that's newer than the time you specified without checking the destination folder.